# Javascript change value to object key (google apps script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hey all I am at a loss and honestly don't know what is happening or why? My knowledge of javascript in general is not that great but I am learning.

I have a object that gets populated by a html document. In that document I have several checkboxes. Some checkboxes are important and they need a VALUE.

```
*
 * Krijg alle verdeler data uit het formulier
 * @param form
 * @return data object
 */
function getS627Data(form) {
  var data = {
    IngediendDoor: form.ingediendDoor,
    Specialiteit: form.specialiteit,
    Aan: form.aan,
    Post: form.post,
    Station: form.station,
    Aanvraag: form.aanvraag,
    Rubriek2ARMS: form.rubriek2ARMS,
    Rubriek2AAndere: form.rubriek2AAndere,
    AanvangDatum: form.aanvangDatum,
    AanvangUur: form.aanvangUur,
    EindDatum: form.eindDatum,
    EindUur: form.eindUur,
    MetOverdracht: form.metOverdracht,
    Lvhw: form.lvhw,
    NodigLvhw: form.nodigLvhw,
    NodigLvhwBis: form.nodigLvhwBis,
    NodigWl: form.nodigWl
  };

  return data;
}
```

So here I populate the object with keys and values

```
/*
 * Al de functionaliteit voor het verdeler formulier
 * @param form
 * @return succes of fail
 */
function writeVerdelerForm(form) {
  try {
    var data = this.getVerdelerData(form);

    if(data.MetOverdracht == NULL) { data.MetOverdracht = 'FALSE'; }
    if(data.Lvhw == NULL) { data.Lvhw = 'FALSE'; }

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
    this.writeData(data, sheet);

    // finalizeer alle sheet gegevens en creeër dan een pdf
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    this.createPDF(sheet, "Verdeler " + data.Lijn, true);

    return this.success();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

And here I tried to do the check to see if the two important keys and values are populated. If not i want to add FALSE to them. Yet they keep on beeing undefined if not checked in the html code.

Am i missing something along the way?

Comment: What is `NULL`?  Is that similar to `null`?

Comment: bad habbits i brought along but if when changed to null it did not fix the issue

Comment: So put `debugger;` right before those statements and use your browsers debugger to inspect the variable.  See what their values actually are.

Comment: debugger is not working (i believe google apps script does not allow it.)

Comment: Then you should `console.log(data)` and inspect the element in the console to see what value those keys have.

Comment: Could you share the rest of the code you're using, including the HTML, so that this issue can be understood and tested? Of course, remove any sensitive information.

Comment: Try js value coercion where undefined is coerced to false.

`if(!data.MetOverdracht) { data.MetOverdracht = false; }
if(!data.Lvhw) { data.Lvhw = false; }
`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript these are special values and should be lower case and unquoted.

```
null
false
true
```

In principle, equality tests should also always use === rather than == (which will attempt a type conversion if required).